# sqlite3 - how to know that the row read is the last row

Tags: c, sqlite

We are using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` to execute a query and read the results. However, we need to know that the row we fetched was the last row without executing the next sqlite3_step statement. Any idea?

The reason for this is a special optimization requirement. To illustrate further, below is the code to read the unknown number of rows from a table. It is required by our code to know the last record so that special actions can be taken.

As you can see from the code, we send last data as NULL to mark it as end of the read. We are doing so that we can directly use the buffer returned by `sqlite3_column_blob` without any malloc/copy.

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
char *data = NULL;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mdb, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
               return -1;
}


while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

       data = (char *)sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0);

       processRecord(data, 0); //data and last row indicator
}

processRecord(NULL, 1); //data and last row indicator
```

We'd like to avoid sending last NULL record. We can achieve that only  if we know in advance that the  record we fetched was the last record.

Any idea how to achieve that?

> **PLEASE NOTE** We are aware that we can reorganize the code as below, but it requires us to duplicate the buffer and too many malloc/copy since sqlite3_step will destroy the previous data. This we are trying to avoid so please DO NOT suggest that.

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
       if(data)
           processRecordAndFree(data, 0); 

       data = duplicate_data(sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0));
}

if(data)
           processRecordAndFree(data, 1);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, short of saving a rows values in other variables and only processing it *after* fetching the next row.

Comment: thanks, that's the second approach which we'd like to avoid!

Comment: Sqlite only fetches rows on demand so it has no way of knowing how many a query will return short of fetching one at a time until no more meet the query constraints. You might not want to do it but you might have to bite the bullet with that approach.

Comment: Did you consider changing the query in order to make sure that the last row can be recognised as such? Either introduce another filed into the query, which gets written to e.g. "last", or find a magic value for one of the other fields. Then make sure that in addition to the actual data, the query returns another, additional, last,  row with that indicator.

Comment: Please make an [mcve], consisting of a tailored toy database (some lines of "create table ..." and "insert ...") and the working code (including the query) without the planned optimmisation. This provides more context and also a foundation on which to put solution proposals.